# RealmSwift + Duplicates of Data

Tags: json, swift, realm

I had some problem understanding on avoiding the duplication of data written into realm database. I have the following Object Model

Person.swift

```
class Person: Object {
    let id = RealmOptional<Int>()
    dynamic var name = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id" 
    }
}
```

Dog.swift

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    var owner: [Person] {
        return linkingObjects(Person.self, forProperty: "dogs")
}
```

And Json data is

```
{
  "id": 1001,
  "name": "Joe",
  "dogs": ["Sally","Molly","Lucy"]
}
```

And after parsing the json data into the variables - personId, personName & dogNameArray, send those data to saveFunc()

```
func saveFunc() {

do {
    let newPerson = Person()
    newPerson.id.value = personId
    newPerson.name = personName

    let newDog = Dog()
    if dogNameArray.count > 0 {
    for dog in dogNameArray {
        newDog.name = dog
        newPerson.dog.append(newDog)
      }
    }

    let realm = try Realm()
    realm.beginWrite()
    realm.create(Person.self, value: newPerson, update: true)
    try realm.commitWrite()

} catch {
    print("create and updating error"
}
```

Problem: The data was created as it should be for the first time but subsequent relaunch of the apps, due to the primaryKey the person data was not recreated which is working as what I intended but the dogs name keeps duplicating. So my question is why are the dog name still added if the person is not overwritten, where did i do wrong?

Comment: That is because Dog does not have primary key, and in that do block you create a dog object every time you want to update the person.

Comment: thnx for the reply! So do u have any suggestion on resolving this considering that the json file has no primarykey for the dogs?

Comment: Sure, please find the answer. You will need to check if person exist, if so, don't create and add dogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can ensure, we check if the person already exist, and if so, don't create and add the dogs:

```
func saveFunc() {

  do {

    let realm = try Realm()
    if let person = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Person.self, key: personId){
       //Nothing needs be done.

    }else {

       //Create Person and dogs and relate them.

      let newPerson = Person()
      newPerson.id.value = personId
      newPerson.name = personName

      let newDog = Dog()
      if dogNameArray.count > 0 {
        for dog in dogNameArray {
          newDog.name = dog
          newPerson.dog.append(newDog)
        }
      }

      let realm = try Realm()
      realm.beginWrite()
      realm.create(Person.self, value: newPerson, update: true)
      try realm.commitWrite()
    }


  } catch {
    print("create and updating error"
}
```

Comment: i got this error 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value 'id' for primary key'

Comment: Oh, it should be the personId.  Edited the answer.

Comment: thnx alot! works like a charm! I have been trying to search for that primary key syntax for almost a week haha.

PS: just to confirm something, am i right to say that if i update my json file sometime later on, I will never get it to update with just this piece of code alone.

Comment: If your JSON changes, say "Joe" has a new `Dog` "Rex", this wouldn't be added.

Comment: In that case, you will need to be able to check if such and such dog object exist, if not, then only add it.  Marius has a hint in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this might be to add a primary key to the linked class `Dog` as well. But if that would be the dog's name, that would cause that another `Person` having a dog with the same name, would share the same `Dog` instance, depending on your real use-case that might be still an adequate solution.

Comment: there is no primary key for dog data and dog name isn't going to cut so i guess I will have to find another solution pertaining to updating check. Thanks for the reply! appreciate it!

Comment: It's been awhile but I am still unable to have a solution for if my json data are updated with changes on Dog Object. Need some serious help

For example if Jim(has primary key) used to have 3 dogs but now are left with two dogs, how can I delete Jim's dogs value and reinsert the 2 dogs changes without affecting other Person Object relationship with their own dogs?

Comment: @Delonn: You will need to process the new related items manually and compare them with the old items. Those which should remain, can be kept and collected in a list, while those which are not needed anymore, can then be deleted directly.